# How to change the word font in email using perl

Tags: perl, email

I want to ask how to change the word font (Calibri to Courier New) in email using Perl script?

I was trying to send a file.txt that contain a table format to an email. 
But, the table did not arrange properly in the email content but the file.txt is arranged nicely.

My result in email:

```
 hello |  morning | 30 | 40 |
 Yes|evening| 30 | 50 |
```

expected output in email:

```
 hello      |  morning    | 30 | 40 |
 Yes        |  evening    | 30 | 50 |

enter code here
```

Below are my code:

#!/usr/bin/perl

```
my $file = '/nfs/site/disks/fm8_pnr_9/users/eewongon/max_cap/vio_table.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Cannot open '$file' for reading: $!";
my $text = do {
local $/;
<$fh>
};
close $fh or die "Ugh: $!\n";

$to = 'someone@somewhere.com';
$from = 'someone@somewhere.com';
$subject = 'Testing';
$message = 'Hi, this is email sent by Perl Script';

open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");

# Email Header
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";

# Email Body
print MAIL "$message\n";
print MAIL "\n$text\n";

close(MAIL); 
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send email in HTML to be able to use a different font. Instead of specifying a font name, however, it's recommended to use the `pre` tag to allow the system to choose an available fixed-width font, since preserving your text-based table formatting is all you want.

```
# Email Header
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
print MAIL "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
# Email Body
print MAIL "<html>\n<body>\n<p>$message</p>\n<pre>$text</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n";
```

Comment: Perhaps your table is in `$message` rather than `$text`? In that case you should put `$message` in the `pre` tag too.

Comment: Perhaps use the `style` attribute to add more explicit CSS to the `pre` tag: `<pre style="font-family: Courier New, monospace">` although it's hard to imagine why your system doesn't render the `pre` tag properly without additional CSS.

Comment: is it possible i just convert all the font in the email into Courier New?

Comment: You can apply the `style="font-family: Courier New, monospace"` attribute to the `body` tag instead to make sure the entire email is in that font, although you still need the `pre` tag to preserve white spaces and newlines.

Comment: print MAIL "<html>\n<body>\n<p>$message</p>\n<pre style="font-family:Courier New, monospace">$text</pre style="font-family:Courier New, monospace">\n</body>\n</html>\n";
I tried use this command but it show syntax error .. is something i do wrongly?

Comment: You need to escape double quotes with a blackslash within double quotes, and also you don't need any attribute for a tag closure like `</pre>`, so you should do this instead: `print MAIL "<html>\n<body>\n<p>$message</p>\n<pre style=\"font-family:Courier New, monospace\">$text</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n";`

Comment: My email sent the result like this 
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<body>
<p>Hi,this email is sent by using Perl Script</p>
<pre>|hello |  morning | 30 | 40 |
 |Yes|evening| 30 | 50 |
</pre>
</body>
</html>
The result dint change to courier new..is it because my table is not in HTML ?

Comment: You must've added double newlines at your Subject line: `print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n"`. Change it to `print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n";` like I showed you above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance :) the email able to show the font

Answer (score 0):

You've got some data in a table format, so you could convert that into a HTML table, which will be rendered correctly in whatever font is used by the email client. And for email clients that don't support HTML, provide a plain text version which would be rendered in a fixed-width font.

The code below parses your pipe-separated CSV file and uses that to build the HTML table and a plain text alternative. Both of which are then added to the `MIME::Entity` object that will create all the headers you need to be able to send it correctly.

I've used `Text::CSV` and `MIME::Entity` but other Perl modules exist that do their job too.

```
use strict;
use MIME::Entity;
use Text::CSV;

my $file="test_input.txt"; # Change this to where your file is
my $subject="An email";
my $from="someone\@somewhere.com";
my $to="someone\@somewhere.com";

# Create the CSV parser. Confusingly the "allow_whitespace" strips whitespace rather than allowing it to pad out fields
my $csv=Text::CSV->new({sep_char => "|", allow_whitespace => 1});

# Build the MIME::Entity object
my $mime_email=MIME::Entity->build(
    From => $from,
    To => $to,
    Subject => $subject,
    Type => "multipart/alternative");

my $html="<table>\n";
my $text;
if(open(my $fh,"<",$file)) # Use the modern way of opening a file
    {
    while(my $line = <$fh>)
        {
        $text .= $line;
        $csv->parse($line);
        $html .= "<tr>";
        foreach my $field ($csv->fields())
                {
                $html .= "<td>".$field."</td>";
                }
        $html .= "</tr>\n";
        }
    close($fh);
    }
$html .= "</table>\n";

$mime_email->attach(Type => "text/plain",Data => $text);
$mime_email->attach(Type => "text/html",Data => $html);

# Send the email
if(open(my $mail,"|-","/usr/sbin/sendmail -t"))
    {
    $mime_email->print($mail);
    close($mail);
    }
```

This will generate an email that looks like which should render the table nicely on a variety of email clients in their preferred fonts.

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----------=_1529920158-30125-0"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: MIME-tools 5.505 (Entity 5.505)
From: someone@somewhere.com
To: someone@somewhere.com
Subject: An email

This is a multi-part message in MIME format...

------------=_1529920158-30125-0
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

hello      |  morning    | 30 | 40 |
Yes        |  evening    | 30 | 50 |

------------=_1529920158-30125-0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<table>
<tr><td>hello</td><td>morning</td><td>30</td><td>40</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td><td>evening</td><td>30</td><td>50</td><td></td></tr>
</table>

------------=_1529920158-30125-0--
```